# Difference in catching promise vs promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

From https://javascript.info/promise-error-handling

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    throw new Error("Whoops!");
  }, 1000);
}).catch(alert);
```

It says the catch in this code block will not work because `here the error is generated not while the executor is running, but later. So the promise can’t handle it.`

However at https://javascript.info/promise-api

```
Promise.all([
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000)),
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("Whoops!")), 2000)),
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(3), 3000))
]).catch(alert); // Error: Whoops!
```

Why does the catch work to catch the Error after 2 seconds?
This looks like it contradicts the 1st code block saying catch won't work

What is different about Promise.all?

Generally how do I investigate the returned promise from Promise.all? I want to index into that "array of promises" to get the state of 1 of them but can't do this syntax `result_promise_all[0]`.

Best if the answer can explain execution order, when which code triggers what to go on microtask and macrotask queues, and when they get off the queue.

Comment: In your first code block, you're throwing inside an asynchronous plain callback.  Nothing can catch that exception.  It just goes back to the event loop where the timer callback was called.  That's true whether you have it wrapped in a `new Promise()` executor function or wrapped in a `try/catch` or anything.  This is just a wrong code structure for Javascript.  So, nothing in that first code block has anything at all to do with promises at all.  Throwing inside a plain asynchronous callback was wrong before we even had promises and it's still wrong because nothing can catch it.

Comment: Exceptions are only turned automatically into promise rejection if you do it in a function declared `async`.

Comment: As for the promise that `Promise.all()` returns, you use it just like you use any other promise.  You use `.then()` or `await` with it.  It will resolve to an array of values or reject to a reason.  If it resolves, you will get an array which you can index into to check on any of the values.  If it rejects, you will get a single reject reason which will be from the first promise that rejected.  If you want all results, regardless of reject or resolve, then you would use `Promise.allSettled()` instead of `Promise.all()`.

Comment: It's very easy to make the first one work. Just replace the `throw` keyword with the `reject()` function.

Comment: It's very easy to make the `Promise.all()` stop working. Just replace the `reject()` function with the `throw` keyword

Comment: `Generally how do I investigate the returned promise from Promise.all` just call it's `.then()` (or alternatively use `await`) just like any other promise: `Promise.all(array_of_promises).then(array_of_results => { doWhateverYouWantHere() })`

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the first and second example is just that you are not rejecting in the first one, while you are rejecting in the `Promise.all`:

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    try {
      throw new Error("Whoops!");
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e)
    }
  }, 1000);
}).catch(alert);



Promise.all([
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000)),
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("Whoops!")), 2000)),
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(3), 3000))
]).catch(alert); // Error: Whoops!
```